# Border Not Resizing With Image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fit a border around a resized image but it takes the dimensions of the original. How do I place a perfect border around an image?

HTML:

```
<div id="show">
 <h1>Featured Items</h1>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" align="center">
            <img src="C:\Users\Gabriel\Downloads\1.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4" align="center">
            <img src="C:\Users\Gabriel\Downloads\1.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4" align="center">
            <img src="C:\Users\Gabriel\Downloads\1.png">
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#show img {
padding-top: 50px;
max-width: 50%;
max-height: 50%;
border: solid 1px #6E4E34;
}
```

Comment: What's the `padding-top` for? that's creating a gap at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `padding-top` and the border will be flush with the `img`

```css
#show img {
max-width: 50%;
max-height: 50%;
border: solid 1px #6E4E34;
}
```

```html
<div id="show">
 <h1>Featured Items</h1>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" align="center">
            <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4" align="center">
            <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4" align="center">
            <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```